# Как перенести андроид приложение с одного идентификатора приложения на другой (перерегистрировать), без потери активов (рейтинга, оценок, отзывов итд)

Tags: android

Можно ли перенести андроид приложение с одного идентификатора приложения на другой идентификатор без потери активов (оценок приложения, отзывов, статистики реализаций, места в выдаче при поиске и т.д.). Т.е. перерегистрировать с сохранением рейтинга, оценок, отзывов и т.д.

Поменять идентификатор приложения, например, **ru.site1.name1** на **com.site2.name2** с переносом активов приложения ru.site1.name1

Т.е. приложение перенести не на другой аккаунт, а на другой идентификатор.
(Я понимаю, что создать с нуля приложение можно с любым идентификатором, речь идет о сохранении активов приложения)

Еще пояснение для чего это надо. Категорически нужно убрать/изменить название сайта в идентификаторе приложения: **ru.site1** в идентификаторе **ru.site1.name1**

Еще одна причина. В приложении нет ссылок на этот сайт. А Гугл требует убрать ссылку на этот сайт. Кроме как в идентификаторе намека на сайт этот нет!

Еще причина. Просто хочу убрать из идентификатора приложения: **ru**

**Зачем уничтожаете очень серьезный вопрос минусами? Это реальная (не учебная) ситуация, связанная с судьбой топового (по своей тематике), кстати, образовательного приложения.**

ЭТО МОЖЕТ КОСНУТЬСЯ  КАЖДОГО, ЕСЛИ НА СООТВЕТСВУЮЩЕМ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЮ САЙТЕ СМЕНИТСЯ КОНТЕНТ! ИЛИ САЙТ ТУПО КТО-ТО ПЕРЕКУПИТ/ПЕРЕРЕГИСТРИРУЕТ. ЧТО И СЛУЧИЛОСЬ С НАМИ. ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ УДАЛЕНО ИЗ ГУГЛ ПЛЕЙ. МЕСЯЦ ПИШЕМ В ГУГЛ ПОЛУЧАЕМ ДЕЖУРНЫЕ ОТВЕТЫ С ССЫЛКОЙ НА САЙТ СО ВЗРОСЛЫМ КОНТЕНТОМ

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134808/discussion-on-question-by-user-mgu-------).

Comment: Ситуация так и не изменилась!

Comment: *САЙТ ТУПО КТО-ТО ПЕРЕКУПИТ. ЧТО И СЛУЧИЛОСЬ С НАМИ.* - есть подозрение, что на самом деле с вами случилось не это, а просто не продлили домен из-за собственного раздолбайства и он совершенно легально ушел в свободное плавание.

Comment: @user7860670
Спасибо. Да, именно так!

Answer (score 1):

Google однозначно и недвусмысленно [не допускает изменение идентификатора существующего приложения](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-application-id):

> Every Android app has a unique application ID that looks like a Java package name, such as com.example.myapp. This ID uniquely identifies your app on the device and in Google Play Store. Once you publish your app, **you should never change the application ID**. If you want to upload a new version of your app, the application ID (and the certificate you sign it with) must be the same as what it was when originally published—if you change the application ID, Google Play Store treats the upload as a completely different app.

Однако если гугл требует убрать ссылку на какой-то сайт, то скорее всего к идентификатору приложения (которое не является доменным именем в интернете) она не имеет отношения, а в приложении действительно где-то присутствует эта ссылка. Также ссылка может быть не в самом приложении, а, например, в privacy policy, сертификатах возрастных ограничений или еще каких-то доп материалах.

Comment: Спасибо. Я все проверил. Очень тщательно! Ссылка - только в идентификаторе приложения! Cайт, который прописан в идентификаторе приложения перерегистрирован и на нем запущен порноконтент. Хотя название его очень мирное: www.EnglishTenses.*