# Какое можно написать имя компании в пакете java если ты единственный разработчик?

Tags: java, android, пакет, публикация-приложений

У меня есть кое-какое название компании которую я сам выдумал и не регистрировал, я единственный разработчик, имею ли я право, могу ли назвать пакет '''com.company.app'''?

Comment: Хоть как, это ваше право

Comment: Можете, но был тут один прецедент: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1373625/11515. Для пакетов классов это не страшно - переименовать можно в любой момент, а вот applicationId переименовать не получится - для него лучше использовать домен, принадлежащий вам, либо абракадабру какую-нибудь, которой никто никогда свой сайт не обзовёт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустимы любые имена, кроме тех, которые начинаются со слов java и чисел, а также содержащих зарезервированные символы. Авторские права не действуют на именование пакетов, только на название самого приложения

Comment: А как назвать свое приложение так чтоб никто так не назвал и что бы было оригинально? Я каждый раз придумываю новое, а когда вижу что такое приложение уже есть придумываю заново.